# Storing Lists in arraylist for ListView

Tags: android, parsing, listview, arraylist

I've parsed xml and saved parsed elements in array list. My aim to use this values for my listviews sections and items.

```
arraylist1 = [Satellite, Satellite, Satellite, Satellite, Map, Map, Hybrid, Hybrid, Hybrid, Hybrid]

arraylist2 = [Roads, Rivers, Buildings, Cars, Animals, Cats, Parcels, Speeds, BlaBla, XlaXla]
```

I've used  `Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(LayerNames);` to eliminate duplicates for first arraylist. It did my stuff. How can i store the other elements like this ;

```
arraylistblabla = 0 index - [Roads , Rivers, Buildings , Cars]
                  1 index - [Animals, Cats]
                  2 index - [Speeds, BlaBla , XlaXla]
```

Thanks in advance for helpings.

**More Explanation**

All i want to do is my listview should be like this;

```
-Satellite ---> Sections
   - Roads ---> ListView items
   - Rivers
   - Buildings
   - Cars
-Map 
   - Animals
   - Cats
-Hybrid
   - Speeds
   - BlaBla
   - XlaXla
```

Unfortunately my listview is looking like below.

```
-Satellite ---> Sections
   - Roads ---> ListView items
-Satellite
   - Rivers
-Satellite
   - Buildings
 -Satellite
   - Cars
-Map 
   - Animals
-Map 
   - Cats
-Hybrid
   - Speeds
-Hybrid
   - BlaBla
-Hybrid
   - XlaXla
```

**EDIT 1 : My listview items adapter.**

```
public class ListViewItemsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<Item> items;
private LayoutInflater vi;
private int resLayout;
private CheckedTextView ctv;
private int selectedIndex;
ArrayList<Item> selectedItems = new ArrayList<Item>();

public ListViewItemsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Item> items) {
    super(context, 0, items);
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    selectedIndex = -1;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    final Item i = items.get(position);
    if (i != null) {
        if (i.isSection()) {
            ListViewItemsSection si = (ListViewItemsSection) i;
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_section, null);
            v.setOnClickListener(null);
            v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            v.setLongClickable(false);
            final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
            sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());
            sectionView.setTextColor(0xffffffff);
        } else {
            ListViewItems ei = (ListViewItems) i;
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_item_entry, null);
            final TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
            if (title != null)
                title.setText(ei.title);
        }
    }
    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: can you show us your adapter and listview code?

Comment: Ok I can show. Its really different. But i think its not about adapter. If i make array list as i mentioned, It wil do my job. But I'll share my adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ExpandableListView` which is designed to hold groups: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: No , i know expandable listview is right but. My aim is not to make expandable listview.

Comment: It is weird that you give me minus for not accepted your answer. Am i have to accept your answer to gain plus from you. This place is not place that satisfy our ego from users. .